# How to set up a timeout for multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a function that parses documents in a MongoDB collection. I would like to set up a timeout for each thread because I won't know if `function2` will take too much time to finish. I tried setting up a `@timeout_decorator.timeout(60, use_signals=False)`, but apparently it does not work.

Better alternatives are considered as well. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

```
def function(collection):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        for document in collection.find({}, no_cursor_timeout=True):
            executor.submit(function2, document)

def function2(collection, document):
    try: 
        ... something ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `executor.submit` all your submitted tasks are returning a `Future` object which has its own way to declare a timeout.

```
def function(collection):
    futures = []
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        for document in collection.find({}, no_cursor_timeout=True):
            future = executor.submit(function2, document)
            futures.append(future)

futures = function(collection)
for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
    result = future.result(timeout=60)
```

You can find more documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.result).

Comment: Thank you, that worked out! I was wondering if with this workaround some threads (especially the first ones) will have a little bit more of time than 60 seconds because they are executed whilst `for` is still running before returning `futures` to the invocation.

Comment: you can just iterate over the `futures` themselves in that case and try to get the `result` since `futures` are unevaluated at that point.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!